# Dual-Boot: Blank screen after choosing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation, nvidia, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have a problem  but I don't know exactly what it is about problem .

Installed Ubuntu  12.04 on in my laptop by two ways : by a bootable DVD and another way by wubi.exe, but it does not work .

When I reboot in my computer with Wubi installed so I see two options for entering the This OS(windows 7 and Ubuntu) but when I select Ubuntu I didn't see anything in my screen laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing again. Download Wubi.exe again. If still does not work then download "EasyBCD" and install it on Windows. Using this software you can add an entry for Ubuntu to the Windows bootloader (i.e, the black screen you seeing at boot time.)